# how to concatenate two images of different dimension in matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I have two images of the same scene but of a different type:
image1:Type RGB ([400 400 3]) and image2:type infrared ([400 400 1]).I am seeking an image by concatenating the image1 and image2 to get an image3 ([400 400 4]).

```
im1=imread('rgbimage.jpg');
im2=imread('infraredimage.jpg');
im3=cat(4,im1,im2);
```

I try with function cat in matlab but I get this error:

```
Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

if someone can help me , thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenating two images with dimensions `[400 400 3]` and `[400 400 1]` to `[400 400 4]` is a concatenation among the third dimension. Use `im3=cat(3,im1,im2);`

Comment: thank you so much its works , after what I understand, cat (dim, A, B) dim  means the most greater dimension between the two images. I'm grateful Mr.

Comment: @PhDMa No. `dim` means the dimension along which you want to concatenate the matrices. So `[A;B]` is same as `cat(1,A,B)` and `[A B]` is same as `cat(2,A,B)`.

Comment: Thank you @Parag S. Chandakkar.